# Call method on activity load, Android

Tags: android, methods, call

I want to call a method as soon as the activity has loaded. The method is a public void. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Call it. What's the problem?

Comment: @codeMagic How is this done?

Comment: That depends on what you want. After the `UI` loads, as soon as the `Activity` is created, etc....? You can call that method in `onCreate()``

Comment: Show us what you have tried by editing your question and provide logcat if it is crashing. Also remember that you will need to `inflate` a `layout` by calling `setContentView(R.layout.someLayout);` before trying to access any `Views` in your method or anywhere else

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the following method

You can call your method in between any one of them on Activity startup all these are called where as onResume is called every time activity resumes it is well explained in ActivityLifeCycle Diagram

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);   

}


@Override
protected void onStart()
{   
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
}


@Override
protected void onResume()
{   
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}
```

You can learn more from  [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

You can learn more from [ActivityLifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

or follow this ActivityLifeCycle from the above

[image]

Comment: Where does this call a method besides those that are part of the `Activity` Lifecycle?

Comment: @codeMagic he says he wants to call method on activity load all these three called when activity loads

Comment: All of these methods fire after activity appears on the screen. I need a method that right before activity launches and loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the activity timeline [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), and check out the startActivity() function [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html).

Hopefully these two will lead you in the right direction for your situation. 
Good luck.